# How to align two rows of images

Tags: html, css

So I have these two rows of divs with images [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n943dwb9/2/) 
You can see that on the left they aligned but on the right when you resize the window top or bottom will stick out. And I want them to be aligned on both sides. How do I fix it?

```
 <div class="latest_wrapper">
  <div class="latest_item"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Men"></div>
  <div class="latest_item"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Women"></div>
  <div class="latest_item"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Watches"></div>
  <div class="latest_item bigger"><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/565b1f797c19420c4d5b89de430751cb/tumblr_inline_nilvxaeMRt1rzpxo3.jpg" alt="40 % off"></div>
  <div class="latest_item bigger"><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/565b1f797c19420c4d5b89de430751cb/tumblr_inline_nilvxaeMRt1rzpxo3.jpg" alt="Sales"></div>
 </div>



 .latest_wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.bigger {
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.bigger:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/n943dwb9/7/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually is very simple to do, check below:

HTML:

```
<div id="imagesDIV">
   <img src="myimage1.jpg" alt=""/>
   <img src="myimage2.jpg" alt=""/>
   <img src="myimage3.jpg" alt=""/>
   <img src="myimage4.jpg" alt=""/>
     .
     .
     .
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imagesDIV {
   width: 960px; // standar width for a webpage
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#imagesDIV img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 20px;  // 0px on top and 20px on the sides
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float the right-most elements on both rows:

```
<div class="latest_wrapper">
  <div class="latest_item"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Men"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
<div class="latest_item"  style="text-align:center;"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Women"></div><div class="break">
</div>
  <div class="latest_item"><img src="http://www.yenmag.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Grumpy-Cat-thumbnail-190x190.jpg" alt="Watches" style="float:right;"></div>
  <div class="latest_item bigger"><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/565b1f797c19420c4d5b89de430751cb/tumblr_inline_nilvxaeMRt1rzpxo3.jpg" alt="40 % off"></div>
  <div class="latest_item bigger"><img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/565b1f797c19420c4d5b89de430751cb/tumblr_inline_nilvxaeMRt1rzpxo3.jpg" alt="Sales" style="float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

**It is important to note that the styling has directly been put into the HTML. I don't know what ID's you want to give them so I kept it inline into the HTML**

And the CSS:

```
.latest_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.latest_item {width: 33%;}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.bigger {
  width: 50%;
}

.break{
  clear:both;
}
```

See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n943dwb9/6/)